# 3 / 2 = 1.0? really?

Tags: java, android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Java Integer Division, How do you produce a double?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3144610/java-integer-division-how-do-you-produce-a-double)

```
double wang = 3 / 2;
Log.v("TEST", "Wang: " + Double.toString(wang));
```

Logcat output...

```
07-04 09:01:03.908: VERBOSE/TEST(28432): Wang: 1.0
```

I'm sure there's an obvious answer to this and probably I'm just tired from coding all night but this has me stumped.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3144610/java-integer-division-how-do-you-produce-a-double http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2187482/is-long-x-1-2-equal-to-1-or-0-and-why

Comment: try `double wang = 3.0 / 2;` instead. You are using integer division so you're getting expected result.

Comment: Expected, i.e. 3 / 2 = round(1.5) = 1

Comment: Thanks for all the super quick answers everybody. I guess it makes sense if they are ints.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In many languages, Java being one of them, the way you write a number in an expression decides what type it gets. In Java, a few of the common number types behave like this<sup>1</sup>:

```
// In these cases the specs are obviously redundant, since all values will be
// cast correctly anyway, but it was the easiest way to show how to get to the
// different data types :P
int i = 1;
long l = 1L;
float f = 1.0f;   // I believe the f and d for float and double are optional, but
double d = 1.0d;  // I wouldn't bet on what the default is if they're omitted...
```

Thus, when you declare `3 / 2`, you're really saying `(the integer 3) / (the integer 2)`. Java performs the division, and finds the result to be `1` (i.e. `the integer 1`...) since that's the result of dividing 3 and 2 as integers. Finally, `the integer 1` is cast to `the double 1.0d` which is stored in your variable.

To work around this, you should (as many others have suggested) instead calculate the quotient of

```
(the double 3) / (the double 2)
```

or, in Java syntax,

```
double wang = 3.0 / 2.0;
```

---

<sup>1</sup> Source: [The Java Tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) from Oracle

Comment: Thanks again for all the answers everyone gave. You explained it very well.

Comment: The default when `f` and `d` are omitted is `double`. [*"A floating-point literal is of type `float` if it is suffixed with an ASCII letter `F` or `f`; **otherwise its type is `double` and it can optionally be suffixed with an ASCII letter `D` or `d`**."*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.2)

Comment: I know this is an old question, forgive me for asking this but I came across it and was wondering something. Why does: `(double)(3/2)` = `1.0`? Is that because it is converting to double AFTER the "integer" division is done? Following that logic, would `(double)(3.0/2.0)` be the only time you'll get `1.5`?

Answer (score 7):

Integer division of `3` by `2` is equal to `1` with residue of `1`. Casting to `double` gives `1.0`

Answer (score 6):

`3` and `2` are integer constants and therefore `3 / 2` is an integer division which results in `1` which is then cast into a double. You want `3.0 / 2.0`

Answer (score 5):

Try: `double wang = 3.0 / 2.0;`

Answer (score 2):

That's the expected behaviour. "3" and "2" are both `int` values, and when you perform `3 / 2` the result will also be an `int` value which gets rounded down to 1. if you cast both to `double` before you perform the division then you'll get the result that you expect:

```
double wang = (double)3 / (double)2;
```