# how to convert a double value to float for the following circumstance?

Tags: java

How to convert a double value to a float value without changing its precision.

for example, if I am having **double var = 1/4** *i.e.(0.25)* 
how to change it to a float type with the value of the variable being **0.25**.

Comment: This is unclear.  What's wrong with `(float)var`?

Comment: Have you tried casting it to a float?

Comment: There is no difference in var's value between `double var = 1 / 4` and `double var = 0.25`.  There is no way to convert a double value to a float value without losing its precision -- that's a little like asking how to convert red to blue without losing any of the red color.  I suggest you read a bit about how floating point values are represented in binary computers; if it doesn't answer your question, it will give you background on how to refine it so we can answer it better.

Comment: Just in case this is the problem: You do realize that `double var = 1 / 4` will give you `0.0`, because the division is of integers and only the result (0) is converted to `double`?

Comment: @arcy: "There is no difference..." - did you try it?

Comment: @RealSkeptic Yes exactly that is happening.

Comment: Then [this question and its answers](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6568847/4125191) may help you.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth (sigh) I use floating point so rarely that this one of those things I often trip over.  Obviously I was thinking about 1.0/4.0, or whatever other way to divide floating point numbers instead of ints.  I was focusing on the OP's desire to convert to double "without losing precision".